# Example sites which use UCC certificates

Tags: https, security-certificate, ucc-certificate

Can anyone point me to a few sites that make use of a UCC (SAN) certificates? I tried to search for this but found a lot of information about UCC certficates without any examples.  As a sanity check before buying/configuring a UCC certificate, I wish to do some basic testing to determine exactly how the certificate will look in different browsers.

Yes, I realize I could just use makecert instead.  I would rather just look at them in the wild.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

kel's answer doesn't give an example and the example in his comment is now using a wildcard certificate.

So try https://www.digicert.com/subject-alternative-name.htm instead ... and just in case they change their certificate, I've attached a screenshot here

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A UC cert works like and standard cert (no green bar, that's and EV cert) but allows multiple domains/sub domains. It's used mainly for exchange servers instead of wildcard certs because exchange is looking for specific certs like mail.yourdomain.com our autodiscover.yourdomain.com instead of *.yourdomain.com.

Hopefully that helps you out.

Comment: Yes, this is all information that I am aware of.  I just want an example site that uses one.

Comment: An example would be: https://mail.thefacebook.com

If you look at the cert details at Subject Alternative Names you will see the others it's good for.